# Click events on pie chart - mpandroid

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using mpandroid charting library. I modified the PieChartRenderer
and was able to get a chart like this.

[image]

**PieChartRenderer**

```
public class ImagePieChartRenderer extends PieChartRenderer {

    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitMaps;
    private Paint mEntryLabelsPaint;
    public ImagePieChartRenderer(PieChart chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitMaps) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
        this.bitMaps = bitMaps;
        mEntryLabelsPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mEntryLabelsPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mEntryLabelsPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mEntryLabelsPaint.setTextSize(Utils.convertDpToPixel(13f));
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IPieDataSet dataSet) {
        drawImages(c);
        super.drawDataSet(c, dataSet);
    }

    private void drawImages(Canvas c) {

        MPPointF center = mChart.getCenterCircleBox();

        // get whole the radius
        float radius = mChart.getRadius();
        float rotationAngle = mChart.getRotationAngle();
        float[] drawAngles = mChart.getDrawAngles();
        float[] absoluteAngles = mChart.getAbsoluteAngles();

        float phaseX = mAnimator.getPhaseX();
        float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

        final float holeRadiusPercent = mChart.getHoleRadius() / 100.f;
        float labelRadiusOffset = radius / 10f * 3.6f;


        labelRadiusOffset = (radius - (radius * holeRadiusPercent)) / 2f;


        final float labelRadius = radius - labelRadiusOffset;

        PieData data = mChart.getData();
        List<IPieDataSet> dataSets = data.getDataSets();

        float yValueSum = data.getYValueSum();

        float angle;
        int xIndex = 0;

        c.save();

        float offset = Utils.convertDpToPixel(5.f);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataSets.size(); i++) {


            IPieDataSet dataSet = dataSets.get(i);

            // apply the text-styling defined by the DataSet
            applyValueTextStyle(dataSet);

            float lineHeight = Utils.calcTextHeight(mValuePaint, "Q")
                    + Utils.convertDpToPixel(4f);

            IValueFormatter formatter = dataSet.getValueFormatter();

            int entryCount = dataSet.getEntryCount();

            mValueLinePaint.setColor(dataSet.getValueLineColor());
            mValueLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(Utils.convertDpToPixel(dataSet.getValueLineWidth()));

            final float sliceSpace = getSliceSpace(dataSet);

            for (int j = 0; j < entryCount; j++) {

                PieEntry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j);

                if (xIndex == 0)
                    angle = 0.f;
                else
                    angle = absoluteAngles[xIndex - 1] * phaseX;

                final float sliceAngle = drawAngles[xIndex];
                final float sliceSpaceMiddleAngle = sliceSpace / (Utils.FDEG2RAD * labelRadius);

                // offset needed to center the drawn text in the slice
                final float angleOffset = (sliceAngle - sliceSpaceMiddleAngle / 2.f) / 2.f;

                angle = angle + angleOffset;

                final float transformedAngle = rotationAngle + angle * phaseY;

                float value = mChart.isUsePercentValuesEnabled() ? entry.getY()
                        / yValueSum * 100f : entry.getY();

                final float sliceXBase = (float) Math.cos(transformedAngle * Utils.FDEG2RAD);
                final float sliceYBase = (float) Math.sin(transformedAngle * Utils.FDEG2RAD);

                final float valueLineLength1 = dataSet.getValueLinePart1Length();
                final float valueLineLength2 = dataSet.getValueLinePart2Length();
                final float valueLinePart1OffsetPercentage = dataSet.getValueLinePart1OffsetPercentage() / 100.f;

                float pt2x, pt2y;
                float labelPtx, labelPty;
                float percentX, percentY;

                float line1Radius;

                line1Radius = (radius - (radius * holeRadiusPercent))
                        * valueLinePart1OffsetPercentage
                        + (radius * holeRadiusPercent);

                final float polyline2Width = dataSet.isValueLineVariableLength()
                        ? labelRadius * valueLineLength2 * (float) Math.abs(Math.sin(
                        transformedAngle * Utils.FDEG2RAD))
                        : labelRadius * valueLineLength2;

                final float pt0x = line1Radius * sliceXBase + center.x;
                final float pt0y = line1Radius * sliceYBase + center.y;

                final float pt1x = labelRadius * (1 + valueLineLength1) * sliceXBase + center.x;
                final float pt1y = labelRadius * (1 + valueLineLength1) * sliceYBase + center.y;

                if (transformedAngle % 360.0 >= 40.0 && transformedAngle % 360.0 <= 130.0) {
                    pt2x = pt1x + polyline2Width;
                    pt2y = pt1y;

                    Log.d(entry.getLabel(), "TWO "+ transformedAngle % 360.0);

                    mValuePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

                    mEntryLabelsPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

                    labelPtx = pt2x;
                    labelPty = pt2y;

                    percentX = labelPtx - 1.5f*offset ;
                    percentY = labelPty + bitMaps.get(j).getHeight() + 2.2f*offset;
                } else {
                    pt2x = pt1x - polyline2Width;
                    pt2y = pt1y;

                    Log.d(entry.getLabel(), "ONE "+ transformedAngle % 360.0);

                    mValuePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);

                    mEntryLabelsPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);


                    labelPtx = pt2x;
                    labelPty = pt2y;

                    percentX = labelPtx + 1.5f*offset;
                    percentY = labelPty - bitMaps.get(j).getHeight() - 0.5f*offset;
                }



                mValueLinePaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j));

                c.drawLine(pt0x, pt0y, pt1x, pt1y, mValueLinePaint);
                c.drawLine(pt1x, pt1y, pt2x, pt2y, mValueLinePaint);


                // draw everything, depending on settings



                drawValue(c,
                        formatter,
                        value,
                        entry,
                        0,
                        percentX,
                        percentY,
                        dataSet.getValueTextColor(j));

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                paint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j));
                c.drawCircle(labelPtx, labelPty, bitMaps.get(j).getWidth(), paint);
                c.drawBitmap(bitMaps.get(j), labelPtx-bitMaps.get(j).getWidth()/2f, labelPty-bitMaps.get(j).getHeight()/2, null );

//                if (j < data.getEntryCount() && entry.getLabel() != null) {
//                    drawEntryLabel(c, entry.getLabel(), labelPtx, labelPty + lineHeight);
//                }

                xIndex++;
            }
        }
        MPPointF.recycleInstance(center);
        c.restore();
    }
}
```

Now I need to be able click on the small circles around the chart. Can someone please point me towards the classes and functions that needs to be modified to achieve this .

Basically I want to invoke the  `onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h)` when I touch the circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's great to see people writing their own renderers like that. Looks awesome!

For your actual question, The class you want is called [`OnChartGestureListener`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/OnChartGestureListener.html). The source code is [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/OnChartGestureListener.java).

First of all, you'll probably need to cache the positions of your circles and bitmaps inside your renderer. Something like this:

```
public ImagePieChartRenderer(PieChart chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitMaps, LabelPointCache labelPointCache) {
    super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    this.bitMaps = bitMaps;
    this.labelPointCache = labelPointCache;
    mEntryLabelsPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mEntryLabelsPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mEntryLabelsPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    mEntryLabelsPaint.setTextSize(Utils.convertDpToPixel(13f));
}

//snip, then:

    c.drawCircle(labelPtx, labelPty, bitMaps.get(j).getWidth(), paint);
    c.drawBitmap(bitMaps.get(j), labelPtx-bitMaps.get(j).getWidth()/2f, labelPty-bitMaps.get(j).getHeight()/2, null );
//then:
    float entryX = dataSet.getEntry().getX();
    float entryY = dataSet.getEntry().getY();
    labelPositionCache.add(entryX, entryY, labelPtx, labelPty);
```

Now create a class that implements that interface, say, `MyOnChartGestureListener`. Now set it to your chart:

```
PieChartRenderer myRenderer = new ImagePieChartRenderer(mChart, mChart.getAnimator(), mChart.getViewPortHandler(), bitmaps, labelPositionCache);
mChart.setOnChartGestureListener(new MyOnChartGestureListener(mChart, labelPointCache));
```

Then you'll need to override the method for the motion event you want to listen for. Let's say you want to listen for single taps 
The following snippet shows how to transform from a raw tapped `x` and `y` to a chart xValue and yValue on the chart:

```
@Override
public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
    float tappedX = me.getX();
    float tappedY = me.getY();
    MPPointD point = mChart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT).getValuesByTouchPoint(tappedX, tappedY);
    Log.d(TAG, "tapped at: " + point.x + "," + point.y);
}
```

You will need some way to check that the `point.x` and `point.y` are within your circle or bitmaps. Then you can check whether the `point.x` and `point.y` from the gesture fall inside it, like this:

```
if (labelPositionCache.contains(point.x, point.y)) {
    float entryX = labelPositionCache.getEntryXForLabelX(point.x);
    float entryY = labelPositionCache.getEntryYForLabelY(point.y);
    Highlight highlight = mChart.getHighlightByTouchPoint(entryX, entryY);
    mChart.highlightValues(new Highlight [] { highlight });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: I updated my answer - what you are asking is a little bit harder than I thought. I think you will have to cache the x and y values for the slice when you cache the label x and y values so you can map between them

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that LabelPointCache is a custom object and doesnot belong to the library itself. Also, won't this logic search for a single point instead of looking for the entire area of  the circle.

Comment: @amarok yes it's a class you would have to write yourself. And yes, you'd have to make some way to check in the area of the circle. It's just a simplification for the sake of an answer - it's clear that you can program well so I think you will be able to finish it from just the sketch I provided

Comment: Got it to work. The only issue is that when I highlight the chart the pie slice does not get elevated. The `onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h)` is invoked but the slice remains the same. It may be an issue of the library itself. [link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1784)

Comment: @amarok glad it works but a pity about the pie slices not getting elevated. i'm not so familiar with pie charts so i don't really know how to fix that problem. in any case, the link to the bug is useful - thanks!